# Is there a way to get the GraphQL schema Object combined by NestJS v6?

Tags: mocking, graphql, nestjs

I'm looking for a way to get the combined GraphQL schema from NestJS v6, in order to mock the schema interface with `addMockFunctionsToSchema` from Apollo, for testing purposes.

i.e. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking/#addmockfunctionstoschema

In short, I need to get anyhow the `schema` object and call :

```
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema })
```

It looks like this was possible on the previous version of NestJS (v5):

e.g. https://github.com/alessandrodeste/graphql-nodejs-typescript/blob/master/src/app.module.ts#L24

Is it not possible anymore to achieve this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean combing module schemas to get one at the app root level?  That can be done in six as before.

Comment: NestJS is combining all the `*.graphql` into a schema object, under the hood. I want to get this `schema` object so I can call `addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema })`

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to mock the schema. I didn't even know it was built-in Nest v6 :)

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
    ...
    mockEntireSchema: true,
    // it's even possible to pass your own mocks if needed
    // mocks: { ... }
    ...
});
```